# Dos condiciones en <c:if>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Quiero agregar dos condiciones al un if en [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl), pero me arroja error.

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX == 0 && ${ISDATE == 0}">
```

> Compilation of JSP File '/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp' failed:
>
> ```
> homeafiliado.jsp:792:61: Syntax error in expression. Encountered "{".
> ```

Quedo atento, Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, sé específico... ¿qué error te aparece? ¿Compilación? ¿Ejecución? ¿Qué mensaje?

Comment: edité la pregunta, ese es el error que dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression Language (EL, el contenido dentro de `${}`) sirve para parsear las expresiones y convertirlos en código Java. No necesitas embeber EL dentro de EL. Tu expresión puede corregirse quitando el `${}` interno.

Debería quedar así:

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX == 0 && ISDATE == 0}">
```

Hasta puedes reescribirlo en un modo más sencillo de entender:

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX eq 0 and ISDATE eq 0}">
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta !

Answer (score 1):

El procesador de UEL solo procesa lo que está dentro de de una construcción `${...}`.

Solución: Toda la expresión debe estar dentro de las llaves.

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX == 0 && ISDATE ==0}"/> <!-- CORRECTO -->
```

Evita incluso que queden espacios en blanco fuera de las llaves,

```
<c:if test="${ISAJAX == 0 && ISDATE ==0} "/> <!-- Error, porque a test se le asignará "false " o "true " (espacio en blanco al final)-->
```

porque tanto `"true "` como `"false "` son convertidos a `false` (https://ideone.com/bHX49T)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta !